# ACR secrets automation on key vault

Tags: authentication, azure-keyvault

We currently store ACR secrets (the access key passwords) in dSMS, and we have to manually rotate those periodically. We want to use key vault to manage the access key if applicable.

For using key vault, I wonder if there are some ref links about step to step instructions? Besides, if using the key vault, what permissions are needed and what's the authentication process?

A side question, do ACR access key passwords accept secrets generated from dSMS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you include more details like what code you tried and what exactly your requirement is?

Comment: I plan to use key vault to manage my ACR access key. And use code to automate that. I wonder how the authentication process works and what permission is needed.